# How to properly propagate gRPC errors Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, grpc

I have been following [this](https://sultanov.dev/blog/exception-handling-in-grpc-java-server/) article.

I am trying to handle gRPC errors gracefully within Spring-boot application, **the main goal is to be able to get the error status in the gRPC client.**

Following the article above, I am stuck on adding the interceptor for the exceptions. How do I do this in Spring-boot app? Through `@Configuration` ?

Or in general, how do you accomplish getting a proper error message through the client of a gRPC call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the interceptor while creation the Server, see its Github code.

```
Server server = ServerBuilder
    .forPort(8080)
    .addService(new GreetingService())
    .intercept(new ExceptionHandler())
    .build();
```

You could also switch to [Lognet's Spring Boot gRPC lib](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter) to use @GRpcGlobalInterceptor.

To use other components in your interceptor declare it as @Component.

Comment: it is exactly as it the article that I linked. I need the exception handler "plugged-in" the Spring Configuration.

Comment: So you want to use e.g. Autowiring in your interceptor class? Declare it as @Component.

Comment: no. I am not sure what I what to use, because this is my question..i.e. I do not know it :)
I need Spring-boot to be able to "plug-in" the exception handler for the gRPC exceptions

Comment: Your question was how to add the interceptor for exceptions, the intercept() call is the answer. If you have a different question, please specify.

Comment: you do not answer my question. you can re-read it. thanks for trying, I appreciate it.

Comment: It works the same way for Spring like for non-Spring applications. Add the line .intercept(new ExceptionHandler()) and your gRPC server should use the exception handler.

Comment: You could use Lognet's Spring Boot starter and use @GRpcGlobalInterceptor, but you ignored that possiblity too.

Comment: Than please add your answer for others with your problem.

Comment: I will if it solves the issue, I am currently testing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the error handling if you can convert your gRPC application as Spring Boot using [yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter), then you can write `@GrpcAdvice`, similar to Spring Boot `@ControllerAdvice` as

```
@GrpcAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

  @GrpcExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
  public StatusRuntimeException handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException cause) {
    var errorMetaData = cause.getErrorMetaData();
    var errorInfo =
        ErrorInfo.newBuilder()
            .setReason("Resource not found")
            .setDomain("Product")
            .putAllMetadata(errorMetaData)
            .build();
    var status =
        com.google.rpc.Status.newBuilder()
            .setCode(Code.NOT_FOUND.getNumber())
            .setMessage("Resource not found")
            .addDetails(Any.pack(errorInfo))
            .build();
    return StatusProto.toStatusRuntimeException(status);
  }
}
```

On the client-side, you can catch this exception and unpack the registerUserResponse as: as

```
} catch (StatusRuntimeException error) {
   com.google.rpc.Status status = io.grpc.protobuf.StatusProto.fromThrowable(error);
   RegisterUserResponse registerUserResponse = null;
   for (Any any : status.getDetailsList()) {
     if (!any.is(RegisterUserResponse.class)) {
       continue;
     }
     registerUserResponse = any.unpack(ErrorInfo.class);
   }
   log.info(" Error while calling product service, reason {} ", registerUserResponse.getValidationErrorsList());
   //Other action
 }
```

I have written a detailed post about gRPC error handling - [Getting Error Handling right in gRPC](https://techdozo.dev/2021/getting-error-handling-right-in-grpc/)